# Building a Python script in Sublime Text

Tags: python-2.7, sublimetext3

Having downloaded Python and SublimeText 3, I try now to write the most straightfoward code : print("Hello world!"). Nothing happens even after having tried more than 10 "solutions". It seems that the file Python.Sublime-build is missing in Python27/Packages/Users/Packages and this prevents from building the script. Is it normal?

I am a beginner, totally lost and really need to find quickly a solution, so thanks in advance.

Comment: The file `Python.sublime-build` is definitely shipped with Sublime text, but it's not in the location you think it is. The file as shipped assumes that there is a command named `python` somewhere in the system path, which is likely your problem (seems to be the most common one people report). I would google how to set the path for your version of Windows and add the python path, or re-install Python and watch for an option that tells it to add itself to the path on your behalf.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will try. When I download Python 3.6, it is written 32-bit, is it a problem for my 64-bit PC?

Comment: No, that works just fine.

Comment: @ OdatNurd Now, the python path is added, but when I build the script nothing happened, it's just written : Build finished. It should print "Hello world!", no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file `Python.sublime-build` is packaged in the `Python` package, which comes pre-installed with Sublime Text 3. It's not in the path you think it is; packages that ship with Sublime Text are stored in `sublime-package` files and are not kept in the same package directory as the one that you use when you custom install your own packages.

The content of that file (as of Sublime Text 3 Build 3126) uses one of the two following commands to execute the "build":

1. `"python -u \"$file\""` as the main build; this causes `python` to execute the current file, with `-u` telling the interpreter not to buffer stdout, so that you can see what your program is doing while it's running.
2. `"python -m py_compile \"${file}\""` as the "Syntax Check" variant of the build. This actually causes your python file to be compiled to a byte code file on disk, but does not actually run it. Hence it's good for checking that you haven't broken anything.

Both of these options just invoke `python` with no explicit path to the python executable (because different people and operating systems put it in different places).

As a test before you try to get Sublime to use python, open a terminal (in Windows it is called "Command Prompt", under OSX it's called "Terminal" and under Linux it's something like "shell", "terminal", "console", "xterm" or some variant on those words) and then execute the command `python` with no arguments.

If you have python installed and fully working, this will show you the version of python you have installed and open an interactive interpreter, so you're good to go. If this gives you your OS's version of "What'cho talkin' 'bout, Willis?", then one of two things is an issue:

1. You don't have Python installed. OSX and most Linux distributions come with a version of python installed, but windows does not. Although you can script Sublime Text using python, it keeps it's python interpreter to itself, so you can't use it to run arbitrary program code. This also means you can't install a python module on your system and then use it in your Sublime Text plugin as well.
2. You have python installed, but it's not in your systems path. In order to fix that you need to find out where python is installed and then add that to your system path. Use google to figure out how to do that for whatever version of the OS you're running.

Now we have a python install and it's in the path, so we're ready to go back to Sublime. In a perfect world, all you have to do is press the build key (<kbd>Ctrl+B</kbd> on Win/Linux, <kbd>⌘+B</kbd> on OSX) and your program will run.

Common pitfalls:

1. You didn't save your python file to disk (or you used the wrong extension). Sublime can only build python files that are stored on disk and which have an extension of `.py`. The Sublime status line at the far right should tell you that the file is a Python file. You can enable `Tools > Save All on Build` if it's not already to ensure that your file is always saved before you build.
2. You're seeing "The system cannot find the file specified" or something similar and you're not on OSX. This means that python isn't in your path you naughty monkey, you. Go back up to the previous steps and be sure that executing `python` from a terminal works, then try again.
3. You're seeing "the system cannot find the file specified" or something similar, but you are on OSX and running `python` from the terminal totally works just fine. Run `which python` from the terminal. Does it say that it's installed in `/usr/bin`? If not, you're probably getting kicked by a OSX feature that does not expose the path to GUI programs the same as it does from the Terminal. Install the [Fix Mac Path](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Fix%20Mac%20Path) plugin for sublime and try again.
4. You don't have the correct build system enabled. For this you probably want to use `Tools > Build System > Automatic` to tell Sublime to automatically select the appropriate build system. If that doesn't work, try manually setting the build system to the Python build system by using `Tools > Build System > Python` from the menu and try again.
5. You have the correct build system enabled, but the wrong variant is being used. Remember that second command up at the top, there? That one doesn't run your program, it just compiles it. You can tell if this is happening by checking if there is a file with the same name but `.pyc` in the same folder as your python source file. To fix this, use `Tools > Build with...` and you should be prompted with two options; `Python` and `Python - Syntax Check`. Pick the first one and try again.
6. You got this far, including step #5 and it's still not working. Did you try to create your own `Python.sublime-build` file? If you did, it might still be there lurking and overriding the built in one. Try removing that file and trying again. A symptom of this is seeing multiple lines that say something similar to `Python` under `Tools > Build System`, or seeing more than just two variants when you choose `Tools > Build With...`
7. Your program runs, but when it gets to the part where it's waiting for you to enter some text (like your name or something), that doesn't work. That's because you can't enter data into a running Python program from Sublime by default. You can try the [SublimeREPL](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeREPL) package; otherwise you have to run your program from the terminal instead.

Hopefully this sorts everything out. If there are any other error messages of some kind something other than these common things has gone wrong.

If you see the build results just say "[Finished in ###s]" but nothing else, and you're sure that your program should be displaying something to the console, the first step would be to double check that the correct variant is being used (i.e. not the "Syntax Check" one) and that you haven't overridden the default `Python.sublime-build` with a different one.

When in doubt, drop back to a terminal and execute `python myprogram.py` and verify that it works the way you expect it to from there. If it doesn't, then Sublime is probably also having the same problem.